# ScriptDB: Custom ID for record for quick bulk updating?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a 20,000 record ScriptDB of product information that I would like to have updated with current price/stock info on an ~hourly basis.
As it stands I am having trouble designing something that doesn't hit against the execution limit headfirst.

Downloaded stockfile is customizeable, currently I have it as JSON, like:

```
[
{"sku":"MYSKU1","price":14.99,"qty":2},
{"sku":"MYSKU2","price":22.99,"qty":25},
{"sku":"MYSKU3","price":91.99,"qty":31}
]
```

Currently I do something like:

```
var prod_feed = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.site.com/myJSONfile").getContentText();
var prod_data = JSON.parse(prod_feed);
var prod_qty = 0, i = 0;
var prod_code = "";
var prod_price = "";

var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var result_array = [];
var result_current = {};
var time_obj = dbDateObject();

for(i = 0; i < prod_data.length; i++) {

    var result = db.query({sku: prod_data[i]["sku"]}).next(); // result will be null if no match

    if (!result) {
    // No match, create new object with this SKU for insertion
      result = {};
      result["sku"] = prod_data[i]["sku"];
    }

    result["qty"] = prod_data[i]["qty"];
    result["price_default"] = prod_data[i]["price"];
    result["last_product_update"] = time_obj;
    result_array[i] = result;

}

var results = db.saveBatch(result_array, false);
```

I can run through about 2,500 records this way, and save them, before hitting time limits.

Is there any way I can use the SKU directly as the record ID?
Then it would be practically 3 lines of code...

```
var prod_feed = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.site.com/myJSONfile").getContentText();
var prod_data = JSON.parse(prod_feed);
var results = db.saveBatch(prod_data, false);
```

If not, any obvious way to increase this efficiency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can use the SKU directly as the record ID?

Sadly, no. `Every ScriptDb object has an id, assigned by the system when it is stored, which is an opaque, immutable string value.` ([ScriptDb documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb).)

However, instead of an array of objects, you could store your products in a single object, with the SKU used as an object attribute. You'll still need to loop through the input, but you'll only have 2 calls to the ScriptDB service instead of thousands.

Try this:

```
  var prod_feed = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.site.com/myJSONfile").getContentText();
  var prod_data = JSON.parse(prod_feed);

  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var result = db.query({type: "products"});
  var products = {};
  if (result.hasNext()) {
    // Projects database object already exists
    products = result.next();
  }
  else {
    // Not found, so create the Projects database object.
    var product_data = new Object();
    products = {type: "products", data: product_data};
  }

  var time_obj = dbDateObject();

  for (var i = 0; i < prod_data.length; i++) {

    if (!(prod_data[i]["sku"] in products.data)) {
      // No match, create new object with this SKU for insertion
      products.data[prod_data[i]["sku"]] = {};
    }

    // Update info for this item
    var item = products.data[prod_data[i]["sku"]];
    item.qty = prod_data[i].qty;
    item.price_default = prod_data[i].price;
    item.last_product_update = time_obj;
  }

  var results = db.save(products);
```

Here's a screenshot from the debugger, showing what the "products" object looks like when retrieved from the ScriptDb. If you could massage your input data a bit, you might be able to get that one-pass write you're dreaming of!

[image: Debugger Screenshot of 'products' object]

Note: I've used `price` and `price_default` as you did... but I suspect that's a typo.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the 6 minute runtime limit that you're hitting then just (a) make your job idempotent and (b) run it again and again until your work is done.

To do (a) - you can "remember" what sku you're up to or have them as lineitems in a spreadsheet and add a "done" column.

To do (b), in your main loop, if you're over 5 mins and under 6 mins, you can quit and reschedule the job to run again in 10 mins (or less but you'll need locks then).